# My program keeps throwing compilation error,I am not able to figure out why the error has occured

Tags: c++, stl

Can't seem to figure out the error that the program keeps throwing.The program keeps throwing the error when I am dereferencing an iterator.Could anyone tell me where did I go wrong?
The problem for the code goes like this "Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of two space-separated long integers."

```
void miniMaxSum(vector<int> arr) {   //arr = {1,2,3,4,5}
    int sum = 0;
    unordered_map<int,int> results;
    for(size_t i = 0;i < arr.size();i++)
    {
        results[arr[i]] = accumulate(arr.begin(),arr.end(),sum) - arr[i];
    }
    pair<unordered_map<int,int>::iterator,unordered_map<int,int>::iterator> mn;
    mn = minmax_element(results.begin(),results.end());
    cout<< *mn.first<<" "<<*mn.second; //line where the error is occuring
}
```

Solution.cpp: In function 'void miniMaxSum(std::vector)':
Solution.cpp:9:9: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream'} and 'std::pair')
     cout<< *mn.first<<" "<<*mn.second;
     ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Think about what you are trying to print and if you are doing that the right way. The error is very clear about where you are wrong.

Comment: I tried using ->,even though it keeps showing the same error.

Comment: Side note, `auto` is your friend. This code is better `auto mn =  minmax_element(results.begin(), results.end());`

Comment: @Afrahmohd What exactly are you trying to print out? Remember you have a pair of iterators, and each iterator is pointing at another pair.

Comment: @Afrahmohd : You have a pair of `std::unordered_map`'s.  By trying to print the first of the pair, you are still pointing to the first unordered map. How will cout print a map unless you tell it specifically what to do.

Comment: @john I am trying to print out the min and max element

Comment: @vishaalShankar But I have declared type of pairs as `unordered_map<int,int>::iterator`.I am creating a pair of iterators of type `unordered_map`

Comment: @Afrahmohd And your elements are pairs? That seems to be the problem, you have more pairs than you realise.

Comment: @john No there are just pair of elements (min,max),but How do i rectify it?

Comment: @Afrahmohd You have a pair of iterators, each iterator is `unordered_map<int,int>::iterator`. Both of those iterators points at another pair. Do you want to print out the first or second int of that pair (or both).

Comment: @Afrahmohd I have no idea. It was you that declared `unordered_map<int,int>` you must know why you have a pair of integers there.

Comment: @john,Actually there are few elements stored by mapping,My task is to find min and max element from those elements which are mapped.To achieve that I have used `minmax_element(-----)` algorithm,but since it returns a pair of iterators (say i),then i can dereference it to obtain min element by `i->first` and max element by `i->second`

Comment: @Afrahmohd The mistake was using `unordered_map` see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** my answer fixes the compilation problem, but OP function does not do what they wanted it to do. John's answer solves the real algorithmic problem.

I reworked your snippet to make it immediately compilable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

void miniMaxSum(vector<int> arr) {   //arr = {1,2,3,4,5}
    int sum = 0;
    unordered_map<int,int> results;
    for(size_t i = 0;i < arr.size();i++)
    {
        results[arr[i]] = accumulate(arr.begin(),arr.end(),sum) - arr[i];
    }
    pair<unordered_map<int,int>::iterator,unordered_map<int,int>::iterator> mn;
    mn = minmax_element(results.begin(),results.end());
    auto minIt = mn.first;
    auto maxIt = mn.second;
    cout<< "key min elem: " << minIt->first << " value min elem: " << minIt->second; 
    cout<< "key max elem: " << maxIt->first << " value max elem: " << maxIt->second;
}
```

The issue is the type of `mn`: `pair<unordered_map<int,int>::iterator,unordered_map<int,int>::iterator>`. `mn` is a `pair`. With `mn.first` you get an iterator to a key-value pair (the `pair` the error refer to). Once you have your `pair` you need to access directly the element you are interested in. I made the passage explicit in my example. You can look here (example at the bottom): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map for the structure of iterators on a `unordered_map` .

PS: you might want to avoid `using namespace std` I did it to keep the differences between your and my snippet to the minimum.

Comment: yeah,sorry I made a change in the line.It's actually arr[i] not arr[0]

Answer (score 1):

So here's the way to solve your problem

```
void miniMaxSum(vector<int> arr) {   //arr = {1,2,3,4,5}
    vector<int> results(arr.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr.size();i++)
    {
        results[i] = accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0) - arr[i];
    }
    auto mn = minmax_element(results.begin(), results.end());
    cout << *(mn.first) << " " << *(mn.second);
}
```

The basic error was that you picked `unordered_map<int,int>` instead of `vector<int>` to store your intermediate results.

And notice that the correct syntax is `*(mn.first)` and `*(mn.second)` because you have a pair of iterators not an iterator pointing at a pair.

[Working example](https://onlinegdb.com/ByZn_YFzS)